# jquery not in a child div (can I use find?)

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I am trying to select a whole div but not a specific div which is inside the main div. Example is as follows:

```
<div id="main_holder">
   <div id="secondHolder">
      <div id="thirdHolder">
         <div id="divIdoNotWantToUse" class="notUsed"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying a simple click to see that when I click on the div, it shouldn't get the alert.

```
$('#main_holder').not('#main_holder.notUsed').click( function(event) {
    alert( 'pullmenu clicked' );
});
```

It's not working, so what is the best approach? Is there a way to use the find in a not selector?

example this works:

```
$('#main_holder').find('#divIdoNotWantToUse').css({ border: '5px solid red' });
```

Solution by Arun:

```
$('#main_holder').click( function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.notUsed').length)
    {
        alert( 'pullmenu clicked' );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#main_holder').click( function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.notUsed').length){
        alert( 'pullmenu clicked' );
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AzEUT/)

Comment: this actually worked great for children elements in the div. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

Add a space to the selector `#main_holder.notUsed` without the space the selector looks for an element with the id `main_holder` and a class of `notUsed` instead of an element within `main_holder` with a class of `notUsed`.

```
$('#main_holder').not('#main_holder .notUsed').click( function(event) {
    alert( 'pullmenu clicked' );
});
```

The issue with this approach is that even though the click event handler is removed from `.notUsed` the event will still propagate to the surrounding `div`s causing the alert to fire.  It may be best to conditionally check the target and then decide whether to stop or allow propagation.

```
$('#main_holder').click( function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).is(".notUsed")){
        alert( 'pullmenu clicked' );
    }
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xBctQ/

Comment: Else, you would try to find an element that has both the id main_holder and the class notUsed. The inserted space tells that the selection continues searching for a child (not necessarily immediate) that has the class notUsed.

Comment: Thanks mate but what if i have content in the div? I want that everything in that div is not clickable.
example: http://jsfiddle.net/xBctQ/1/

Answer (score 2):

I can see an error in your markup:

```
<div id="thirdHolder>
   //--------------^---------a closing " required
```

although its not a big issue but you need text in the markup to see the effect of click:

```
<div id="main_holder">Used
   <div id="secondHolder">Used
      <div id="thirdHolder">Used
         <div id=" divIdoNotWantToUse " class="notUsed">Not Used</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If this is corrected then you can try this script:

```
$('#main_holder').children().click( function(event) {
    alert( 'pullmenu clicked' );
});
$('#main_holder .notUsed').click( function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can stop the event bubbling via `.stopPropagation()`.

#### [Find in FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cZDCL/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
$('#main_holder').click(function (event) {
    alert('pullmenu clicked');
});

$('#divIdoNotWantToUse').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fMRf/)